# Cannot connect to WAN sites over WiFi on Alarmpi (Arch Linux)

Tags: wifi, archlinux

I'm having an odd problem. I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3:--- I can connect to my Wifi and to WAN sites on Raspbian. And, on Alarmpi (Arch Linux) I can connect fine over ethernet.

However, on Alarmpi, if I try connecting via Wifi (various methods, netctl, wpa_supplicant, networkmanager), I can connect to my Wifi, and I can ping other machines on my LAN, but I cannot connect to the Internet (or ping WAN addresses like google.com or 8.8.8.8).

I'm really perplexed and Google searches haven't revealed anything of help.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the firewall.

Try in the terminal,

```
service iptables stop 
or
/etc/init.d/iptables stop
```

Comment: I tried this (`systemctl stop iptables.service`), but it didn't make any difference. I don't think it's a firewall issue, since I can connect via eth0 without issue.

Comment: Did you check routing table as well?

Comment: Agreed, it is most likely the routing table. Examine the output of 'ip route'. You should have a default route, something like 'default via [blah blah]'. Based on your description of the problem (pinging local net, but not global internet), this is most likely what is missing.